# Is there a way to use a table in onFirstPage in SimpleDocTemplate

Tags: reportlab

is there a way to use a table in onFirstPage in SimpleDocTemplate. It is a flowable object and is supposed to be the first argument. But i want to display data that should be displayed on all pages.

```
doc.build(flowables, onFirstPage=myFirstPage, onLaterPages=myFirstPage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really possible.

What are you trying to accomplish?  You should be able to get a table on the first page using frames in the PageLayout to place it wherever you want.

Comment: I'm really new to reportlab, thanks for the reply, i want a table in the header that displays on every page

Comment: There's not really a good way to do this.  You'd be better off just drawing lines and text in the shape of a table at the top of the page.

Comment: Thats what i ended up doing, thanks for the help, appreciate it